# Getting errorProvider to execute on button click

Tags: c#, validation

I've been trying to do this for a while now and just cannot get the code to execute the way I want it to. When running the program in C# visual studio, I click the submit button and instead of alerting me with errors because of the blank text boxes, it does nothing. I wanted to know how to execute the errorProvider or "errorCheck" in my code within the SUBMIT button (txtSubmit) so that it brings up the errors.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;    //input output external files (.text)
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;   //handles errors
using System.Xml;


namespace H1

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Exits the application when pressed
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //clears the fields when clicked
        txtPid.Text = "";       //Patient Information Fields
        txtPname.Text = "";
        txtPphone.Text = "";
        txtPaddress.Text = "";
        txtPemail.Text = "";
        txtPhysician.Text = "";     //Last visit fields
        txtDate.Text = "";
        txtReason.Text = "";
        txtIid.Text = "";       //Insurance information fields
        txtIcompany.Text = "";
        txtIphone.Text = "";
        txtIinsured.Text = "";
    }

    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] dat = new string[12]; //Declare new string array, 12 because 0 is included in count
        dat[0] = txtPid.Text; //Patient Information Fields
        dat[1] = txtPname.Text;
        dat[2] = txtPphone.Text;
        dat[3] = txtPaddress.Text;
        dat[4] = txtPemail.Text;
        dat[5] = txtPhysician.Text; //Last visit fields
        dat[6] = txtDate.Text;
        dat[7] = txtReason.Text;
        dat[8] = txtIid.Text; //Insurance information fields
        dat[9] = txtIcompany.Text;
        dat[10] = txtIphone.Text;
        dat[11] = txtIinsured.Text; //Array is now fully populated
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("PatientInfo.txt"); //Declare a new writer
        for(int i = 0; i < dat.Length; i++) //Iterate through the array
    {
        sw.WriteLine(dat[i]); //Writes the current position in a new line to specified file
    }
        sw.Close(); //Close our writer, don't need unused junk left open

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("PatientInfo.txt"); //Specifies a new stream reader to read the file "File.dat"
        String dat = sr.ReadToEnd(); //Reads the file until end and assigns it to the string "dat"
        sr.Close(); //Close reader
        dat = dat.Replace("\r", ""); //Removes all instances of carriage return, for handling/compatibility
        string[] arr = dat.Split('\n'); //Splits the string into an array based on the new line character
    }

    private void txtPid_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        // defines match
        Match m = Regex.Match(txtPid.Text, @"\b[0-7]{7}\b");    //regular expressions

        if (m.Success == false) //if does not match then provide below message
            errorCheck.SetError(txtPid, "Patent I.D. must be 7 characters.");   //error message
        else errorCheck.SetError(txtPid, "");   //clears
    }

    private void txtPname_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtPname.Text.Length < 3)   //checks to see if there are less than 3 characters
        {
            errorCheck.SetError(txtPname, "Please enter the first and last name.");
        }
        else if (txtPname.Text.IndexOf(' ') == -1)
        {
            errorCheck.SetError(txtPname, "Must have both names seperated by a space.");
        }
        else errorCheck.SetError(txtPname, "");     //clears
    }

    private void txtPaddress_Validating(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtPaddress.Text == "")
        {
            errorCheck.SetError(txtPaddress, "You must enter the address.");
        }
        else errorCheck.SetError(txtPaddress, "");  //clears
    }

    private void txtPphone_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtPphone.Text != "Valid")
        {
            errorCheck.SetError(txtPphone, "Telephone Number must be in proper format");
        }
        else errorCheck.SetError(txtPphone, "");
    }

    private void txtPemail_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtPemail.Text == "") //checking for blanks
        {
            errorCheck.SetError(txtPemail, "You must enter an e-mail address.");
        }
        else if (txtPemail.Text == "@") //checking for @
        {
            errorCheck.SetError(txtPemail, "You must enter a valid e-mail address.");
        }
        else errorCheck.SetError(txtPemail, "");
    }

    private void txtIid_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Match m = Regex.Match(txtIid.Text, @"\b[0-7]{7}\b");

        if (m.Success == false)
            errorCheck.SetError(txtIid, "Insurance I.D. must be 7 characters.");
        else errorCheck.SetError(txtIid, "");   //clear
    }

    private void txtIcompany_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtIcompany.Text == "") //checking for blanks
        {
            errorCheck.SetError(txtIcompany, "You must enter an Insurance Company.");
        }
        else errorCheck.SetError(txtIcompany, "");
    }

    private void txtIphone_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtIphone.Text != "Valid")
        {
            errorCheck.SetError(txtIphone, "Telephone Number must be in proper format");
        }
        else errorCheck.SetError(txtIphone, "");

    }

    private void txtIinsured_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtIinsured.Text.Length < 4) // checking entry length
        {
            errorCheck.SetError(txtIinsured, "Please enter the first and last name.");
        }
        else if (txtIinsured.Text.IndexOf(' ') == -1)  //checks for space
        {
            errorCheck.SetError(txtIinsured, "Must have both names.");
        }
        else errorCheck.SetError(txtIinsured, "");
    }

    private void txtDate_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtDate.Text == "")
        {
            errorCheck.SetError(txtDate, "Must enter a correct date.");
        }
        else errorCheck.SetError(txtDate, "");
    }

    private void txtPhysician_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtPhysician.Text == "") //checking for blanks
        {
            errorCheck.SetError(txtPhysician, "Must enter the Physician's name.");
        }
        else errorCheck.SetError(txtPhysician, "");
    }

    private void txtReason_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtReason.Text == "")
        {
            errorCheck.SetError(txtReason, "Must enter a reason for visit.");
        }
        else errorCheck.SetError(txtReason, "");    //clears
    }

}
}
```

Comment: What about `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`, instead of comparing with ""

Comment: I tried that, did not work.